# Error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0,in JENKINS

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to deploy my project using `Jenkins` with `Bitbucket`, When I build I get this error:

```
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError  Unsupported major.minor
> version 51.0
```

I searched for this and found some solution regarding this.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError happens because of a higher JDK
>   during compile time and lower JDK during runtime

```
 - J2SE 8 = 52
 - J2SE 7 = 51
 - J2SE 6.0 = 50
 - J2SE 5.0 = 49
 - JDK 1.4 = 48
 - JDK 1.3 = 47
 - JDK 1.2 = 46
 - JDK 1.1 = 45
```

I have installed java 1.6.

Previously while configuring Jenkins I was using "Install automatically option". at the time of build , Jenkins was downloading java 1.8.
Now I have changed the option as mention in image. I have set the path of the jdk which is installed in my system. now it should use java 1.6.

> but still I am getting the same error while building the project.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least JDK7, that error is likely the result of running that code on Jenkins with the JRE6 embedded in that `jdk1.6.0_45` (jre subdirectory).

You have two options: reconfigure Jenkins with a newer JDK (i'd say this is the way to go) or compile your code (**libraries included**) with Java 6 if you don't need any of the post-1.6 features.

Comment: I dont want to use jdk 7. the reason behind it , I have written my all code in jdk 6. if i use jdk 1.7 it will cause lot of error in my code.

Comment: @varun are you sure you are getting errors with Java 7? Java6 is EOL, i'd recommend to fix every error and switch at least to Java 7. Btw, if you want to stay with java 6 then you need to compile *everything* with java 6, some of the libraries you use as jar could be compiled with java 7, you'll need to compile them from source.

Comment: I have install Java 1.7 build in process as soon I get the result I'll let know. as u recommended to use Java 1.7